# Android Firebase changing user email address error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

When trying to let a user change his/her email address Firebase gives an error. Not an error for invalid email or password, but the default error message (the third Toast message "an error occured").
In the logcat of the application are no errors. It says "success".
What could be the source for the error in Firebase?

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
                    mFirebaseRef.changeEmail(email, mail, password, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "email address is changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            // error encountered
                            switch (firebaseError.getCode()) {
                                case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unknown user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "an error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: There are many more error codes than the ones you're handling here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/FirebaseError.html. It will be a lot easier to help you if you show the value that you get back out of `getCode()`. You can also get more information if you `Log.e("Activity", firebaseError.toString())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @FrankvanPuffelen!
The error code is an INVALID_EMAIL. Which is strange, because to test it I used existing email addresses.